# Equivalent statements conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space and $X,Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ two random variables. Now, assume $f$ is a function such that $\mathbb{E}[|f(X,Y)|] < \infty$. If $X$ an $Y$ are independent I know that the following statement holds:
$$ \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)| X] = \mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)]_{x = X}. $$

My (probably rather obvious) questions are:

1. By applying the expectation I get from above
   $$ \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)] =  \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)]_{x = X}]. $$
   Is the reverse direction also true?
2. Can I use the above statement as a direct definition of independence in the sense of "$X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if the above statement holds for all $f$"?
3. However, I have some difficulties in intuitively handling the expression $\mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)]_{x = X}$. Some elaboration with examples would be great! I am not sure whether I understand the above statement intuitively.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is 2 supposed to read "... if and only if the above statement holds for all $f$" ?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, exactly.

Comment: The intuition is $$E(f(X, Y) \mid X = x) = E(f(x, Y) \mid X = x) = E(f(x, Y)).$$ Actually this is a proof of the identity.

Comment: Note that $E[f(X,Y) \mid X = x]$ is formally not the same as $E[f(X,Y) \mid X]$. The former is a number (or a function) and the latter is a random variable. Informally and for understanding, you can, however, think of them as "the same thing". I think this distinction is important for @Galois1763's understanding in 3.

Comment: What do you mean by 'is the reverse direction also true" in 1.?

Comment: @Therkel My bad. I was concerned somehow whether the statement on the top and under bullet 1. are equivalent.

Comment: @Mason I am aware of this and of the formal proof. I was just puzzled about the intuitive understanding in terms of the independence assumption, i.e., the conditional expectation of $f(X,Y)$ given $X$ is $\mathbb{E}[f(x,Y)]_{x = X}$ what does this tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where you are naturally led to use the result: Let $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be independent integrable real valued random variables. For $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, let $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $E(S_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_{n - 1}) = S_{n - 1} + E(X_n)$.